# Wakanda 2.7.0 Studio not showing new class methods

Tags: wakanda

Wakanda Studio 2.7.0 (and the previous version) do not update the visual model with new class methods that are created using studio.  I recall this was acknowledged quite some time ago, but with 2.7.0 it has not been addressed.

What is the status can can you confirm that the Wakanda team have an objective to resolve this issue?